# Animate overlayed line plot R

Tags: r, gif, gganimate

I am trying to animate a line plot that has two series overlayed on each other. Originally tried using ggplot however the plot does not present as it should, and didn't like overlayed series, so I have used base R to build. I have overlayed the plots using `points()` and the tried to use `animate()` however this hasn't worked as I thought. Packages loaded are `tidyverse`, `gganimate`, and `gifski`.  If anyone can help provide suggestions on how to animate, then save to GIF, I would be very appreciative. Script used below.

Note: Var1 and Var3 are of the same continuous scale, while Var2 and Var4 are of the same continuous scale. Thus, the plot should show a direct comparison of the line created by Var1 x Var 2, versus Var3 x Var4. `x_low_lim` `x_high_lim` etc are simply `x_low_lim <- min(df$Var1, df$Var2)` and so on.

Data (actual df 1561 obs)

```
Var1         Var2        Var3        Var4 
0.01143254   402.15      0.01022165  359.556
0.01139741   491.618     0.010139741 359.33 
0.01137335   401.345     0.01015561  358.373
0.0113451    401.071     0.01011026  357.417
0.0113151    401.472     0.0100628   357.039
0.01128512   401.874     0.01001548  356.661


 p <- plot(x = df$Var1, y = df$Var2, type = "l",
  xlim = c(x_low_lim,x_high_lim),
  ylim = c(y_low_lim, y_high_lim),
  col = "red", xlab = "Vel", ylab = "For", main = "For-Vel") + 
  abline(v = 0) + 
  abline(h = df$Var2.left[1]) +
  points(x = df$Var3, y =df$Var4, type = "l", col = "blue") +
  legend("topright",c("Left", "Right"), text.col = c("red", "blue"))

animate(p, fps = 10, width = 750, height = 450)
anim_save("For-Vel.gif")
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that code? First. As the name `gganimate` suggests it's an extension package to ggplot. So. It will not work for base R plots. Second.  Adding layers via "+" like in ggplot will not work for base R plots. Third. What kind of animation do you have in mind?

Comment: Hi Stefan, the entire dataset shows a loop (think like a nautilis shell). The data is in a time series and I would like it to start animating from the first data point to the last, along the time series. I didn't think `gganimate` would work given its link to `ggplot` however my inexperience said to give it a go anyway. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Hi @youngtred. I would recommend to revise your question and to split it in two parts. Solve the problem step by step. (; First step and question is to get a static plot. As your final goal is to have a animated plot I would recommend ggplot2. At least from the code you posted I don't see why ggplot2 should not work in your case or why base R should do better. I recommend to post the code you tried in ggplot and perhaps an example of how the final plot should look like. Second step and question is how to convert the static plot to a dynmic plot, e.g. by using gganimate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it go and see what I come up with.